How do I set limits on number of items I can add to my shopping cart using Odoo 16?
So I am making a website that includes online courses, which will be for sale. I want to find a way to put limits or rules on how many courses or items you can add to your cart. It can be based on the number of credits a student has or another factor.
I am using Odoo 16, without creating a new module. Is there any way for me to do this?
Any help would be appreciated.
I tried writing a new record rule and making it work, but that did not work .
